# Webview issue with loading images from HTML

Tags: android, html, css, image, webview

I have a Webview in which i load HTML data (and also using css) using the following code:

```
final String mime = "text/html";
final String encoding = "utf-8";
final String htmlData = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />"
            + aboutDescriptions[index];

    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlData, mime,
            encoding, null);
```

in the HTML i load images like this:

```
&lt;img src=\"file:///android_res/drawable/myimage.jpg\"/&gt;
```

in my css i have the following defined for the "img" tag:

```
img {
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
}
```

On my (real) 2.3.3 Android Phone and my Google Nexus 7 Tablet everything is working as expected (the HTML renders fine using the css and the images are displayed).

However on a real Galaxy Nexus phone and on many emulated devices the images are not shown at all. What am i doing wrong? I have experienced quit a few bugs allready with WebView, hopefully this is one that can be fixed? (perhaps a CSS tweak?)

Comment: Where is this 'file:///android_asset' situated? I think you should use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` if you want to open something from sd card.

Comment: do you tried relative path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to fix this by changing my css like this:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```